# How can I play HDS vod stream using html5 video tag

Tags: html, html5-video, wowza

I am using following code to play manifest.f4m vod stream through wowza media server.but it is not working Please help if anybody knows.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://localhost:1935/vod/_definst_/mainVideo/smil:mainVideo.smil/manifest.f4m" type="video/mp4">

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: your video format is mp4 or not

Answer (score 2):

As of this time, HTML5 does not support raw f4m. Consider converting the video file to a compatible format.

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://localhost:1935/vod/_definst_/mainVideo/smil:mainVideo.smil/manifest.f4m" type="video/f4m">

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

try this code...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it is not working on my side.

Comment: Video path is correct because it works when i play it on wowza test flash player.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc If this is true, you should answer the question saying "this isn't possible"